# What is the suitable data structure for dealing with some sets in this scenario in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a graph containing some nodes. I defined a set named `nodes` that contains all of nodes in the graph (I put the node numbers in the set `{1,2,3,4,...}`).

I also have defined a set for each node (for example node #1) which contain just the number of the node, ( that means `{1}` ) using this code:

```
setsofnode=Hash.new
nodes.each do |i|
  setsofnode[i]=Set.new()
  setsofnode[i].add(i)
end
```

which `setsofnode` is a hash of sets.

I need to merge some of the sets, For example set of node #1 and set of node #2. which will be `{1,2}` and use this set for each nodes rather than using `{1}` for node 1 and `{2}` for node 2.

I was thinking of replace this new set with previous sets in `setsofnode`, which means:

```
{1} --> {1,2}
{2} --> {1,2}
```

but this will take a large amount of space if I merge large number of nodes in this way and I will have so many duplicate sets. So how can I refer node #1 and node #2 to `{1,2}` without defining the set twice in `setsofnodes`? Should I change my datastrcutrec(setsofnodes)? Is these more efficient way to define a data structure for storing sets that each node is contained in?

Comment: As a programming style note: In Ruby, variables are snake_case. There's a huge difference in readability between `setsofnode` and `sets_of_node`. You might not be programming professionally, but if that's your goal or you want to share code, then you'll need to conform to the norm.